# Unobvious model change

Tags: scope, angularjs, event-listener

In a angularjs/express/postgres app, i want to load big list of json object from the db to the client.
Each json object is it's self pretty big. Each on is stored in a separate row.
So i want to display each json object as soon as they are read from db.

I've found the EventSource api, to progressivly send the json object from server to client.
Which works fine.

Then i want to display them on my view as soon as possible.

Working with event source include working with event listeners.

As explain here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/xMkm81VkR9w
the angular won't notice the change of the model since the scope modification occurs outside the angular world, inside a event listener.

There is a way to trigger to dirty cheking by calling $scope.$apply().
But since my list as more than 200 element, this error is triggered:

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

So i'm wondering if there is another way to trigger the dirty checking ? Maybe another way to approch my issue.

EDIT:
The title was changed after reflection on the real problem

Comment: I'm maybe not right about why the error is raised.
If i treat just one json object (adding it to the list model), i still have the same error

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think that 10 $digest problem is linked to the size of data. Rather, I would suspect that you are re-creating a container (an array?) holding model data. It is next to impossible to help without seeing more code, especially the way you update AngularJS model. Could you send a jsFiddle / plunk better illustrating your approach?

Comment: sorry i forget about that:
http://jsfiddle.net/EKUbB/
$movieStream is a factory of EventSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the issue come from the partial, where i add filter expression in a ng-show directive
 My bad